# Meta-regression using restricted cubic splines (with rma() from the metafor package and rcs())

Tags: nonlinear-regression, meta-analysis, nonlinear, splines, meta-regression

I would like to compile data from several published studies. I am trying to conduct a meta-regression using restricted cubic splines to analyse and plot the association between two variables (x and y), which is not linear.

Here's a simplified version of the code I used to fit the restricted cubic splines in the meta-regression:

```
library(metafor)

spl <- rma(y, y_se, mods = ~ rcs(x, c(1,2,3,4,5)), data=data, method="DL", random = ~ 1 | id)
```

However, the estimates of the regression between the knots are very high (+1111) and low (-1826), when I expected much less variation (-2 to 2).

```
    Model Results:

                          estimate
intrcpt                    89.7615
rcs(x, c(1,2,3,4,5))x        14.0133
rcs(x, c(1,2,3,4,5))x '     -112.4379
rcs(x, c(1,2,3,4,5))x ''    1111.1094
rcs(x, c(1,2,3,4,5))x '''  -1826.6025
```

And when I plot these, it gives me also a very odd plot:

```
with(predict(spl, dose), plot(dose, pred, type = "l"))
```

[image]

Do you have an idea why? Is this because rcs() cannot be used with rma()? If this is the problem, what is the alternative to include a restricted cubic spline model within rma()?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 1) `rma()` does not have a `random` argument. 2) You appear to pass the SE of the estimates as the second argument. However, the second argument of `rma()` is for the *variances*. Either use `rma(y, y_se^2, ...)` or `rma(y, sei=y_se, ...)`. 3) You also may want to mention that `rcs()` comes from the `rms` package. Note that 1) and 2) do not explain these strange results. In general, `rma()` plays nicely with `rcs()`, but unless you provide a fully reproducible example illustrating the problems you are encountering, it will be next to impossible for me (or anybody else) to help.

Comment: Unfortunately the plot still looks odd. I think that there is something wrong with the way I am plotting the results... Do you have an example on how to plot a line with the results of a rma() including restricted cubic splines and the 95% confidence interval upper and lower bounds?

Comment: Without more detail this is going to be hard to unpick as @wolfgang states. We do notkknow (a) how many studies you have (b) what x is (c) what scientific question is leading to a spline function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate the use of a restricted cubic spline with metafor.

```
library(metafor)
library(rms)

### load data
dat <- get(data(dat.raudenbush1985, package="metafor"))

### plot data
with(dat, plot(weeks, yi, pch=19, xlab="Weeks", ylab="Standardized Mean Difference"))
xs <- seq(0,25,by=1)

### linear model
res <- rma(yi ~ weeks, vi, data=dat)
lines(xs, predict(res, newmods=xs)$pred, lwd=2)

### model with restricted cubic spline
knots <- c(1,2,5,10)
res <- rma(yi~rcs(weeks,knots), vi, data=dat)
lines(xs, predict(res, newmods=rcspline.eval(xs, knots, inclx=TRUE))$pred, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image: Scatterplot with Regression Lines]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed: I used your example and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!